# Pass Array from Javascript to Controller in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have checkboxes that, when they are selected and I click on the button, call a JavaScript function where I send the values of the selected items.
I would like to know what I should change in the JavaScript function to send the values to a controller in asp.net mvc.

Button

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="getChecked()">
```

Checkboxes

```
   @foreach (var item in Model.Attachments)
{                
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="item" value="@item.Id" >
}
```

JavaScript Function (Here I need help to send array to controller?)

```
function getChecked() {
 
 var arr = [];

 checked_items = ''
 var items = document.getElementsByName("item")
 for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       if (items[i].checked)
        arr.push(item[i]);
        }
        alert('JAVASCRIPT : Checked items are : ' + arr);

    }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Selected(Guid[] item)
 {
    return View(item);
 }
```

Comment: If you are using vanilla JS or something like jquery, you can use the fetch api to do it, or use ajax. https://gomakethings.com/how-to-use-the-fetch-api-with-vanilla-js/

Comment: You can query all checked checkboxes using a CSS selector: `document.querySelectorAll('[name="item"]:checked')`. Also, don't use global variables; stick to `let` and `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i have understood from your question, one possible fix to address this issue can be using an AJAX call to pass your array to the controller like this:

```
function getChecked() {
    var arr = [];
    var items = document.getElementsByName("item");
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].checked) {
            arr.push(items[i].value);
        }
    }
    debugger;
    alert('JAVASCRIPT : Checked items are : ' + arr);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/Controller/Selected', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            // Handle the response from the server if needed
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(arr));
}
```

And if you're using jquery u dont have to initialize `xmlHttpRequest()`, you can simply do this:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/Controller/Selected',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(arr),
        success: function(response) {
            // Handle the response from the server if needed
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

I hope this helps.